# How do I get if a subreddit that the bot is trying to fetch doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have some code that I got together from the help of this community and I don't know how to get if the bot can't send a random post from a subreddit because it doesn't exist? This is the code:

```js
if (msg.content.startsWith('-reddit ')) {
 const subname = msg.content.slice(8);
 const mxlenght = 30;
 if (subname.length >= mxlenght) {
  msg.reply('Ez a subreddit név meghaladja a 30 karakteres maximumot.');
 } else {
  function loadMemes() {
   // Fetch JSON
   return (
    fetch(
     'https://www.reddit.com/r/' + subname + '.json?limit=800&?sort=hot&t=all'
    )
     .then((res) => res.json())
     // Return the actual posts
     .then((json) => json.data.children)
   );
  }

  function postRandomMeme(message) {
   return loadMemes()
    .then((posts) => {
     // Get a random post's title and URL
     const { title, url } = posts[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)
     ].data;
     // Create the embed
     const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
      title,
      image: { url },
      footer: { text: 'Subreddit : r/' + subname },
     });
     // Send the embed
     return message.channel.send(embed);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
  }

  // Usage:
  postRandomMeme(msg).catch(console.error);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I believe the problem is with the `URL`. First of all, you are fetching data from `www.reddit.com`, when you should be looking at `api.reddit.com`. Secondly, there needs to be a slash after the subreddit name.

Here's what the finished `URL` should look like:

```js
`https://api.reddit.com/r/${subname}/.json?limit=800&?sort=hot&t=all`
```

Comment: It works and it sends it with no problem, my problem is I want to make it so that if the subreddit that the user requests with the -reddit (sub name) doesn't exist it replies in the chat with "That doesn't exist" or something like that.